# Questions about news and other developing stories

Tags: discussion

What are our policies about questions related to news and other developing stories. See for example my recent answer to [Are chemical weapons being used in the civil war in Syria?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/are-chemical-weapons-being-used-in-the-civil-war-in-syria)

The facts obviously reflect the most recent snapshot of the events and will continue to evolve as more information is verified by the media and other involved agencies. What to do? Update the answer as more facts emerge? Or treat it as a snapshot at the time of the asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we should do is add a post notice warning our visitors that the event is current. This serves two purposes:

- it warns the user about the potential low quality of the sources and
- it acts as a reminder that the answers will need to be reviewed later

If a questions should have one, flag the mods and they'll add one for you.

Comment: I've added an example notice below.

Answer (score 0):

I think current topics is kinda... uninteresting to have questions about, since they easily get in actualized. If someone doesn't update the answer and current 'facts' become lies the next day, the side is continue to spreading the lies.

Also things in newspaper are saturated with propaganda, and are always highly subjective, especially things being RIGHT NOW.

Closing down every question about current things is not feasible though...

Comment: Yes. I think we should think of a policy on current topics.